# Have an Abstract Action wait for a Mouse Event?

Tags: java, mouseevent, action, abstract-action

I am trying to write an AbstractAction class which waits for a mouse click event and then processes the Object clicked. Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Also, if the user clicks the wrong type of object, would like to ask the user to try again.

```
private class MyAction extends AbstractAction implements EventListener {

    MyAction() {
        super("Do something...");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Wait for User to click to select Object
            Object o = ...;
            // Do something with object that was clicked/selected
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You never want to "wait" in a program that uses an event-driven programming paradigm and instead should have the program alter the behavior of its listeners depending on its state. As for your specific problem, if you don't get a decent answer soon, consider telling and showing more details of the problem, including possibly an [mre] program code post with the question.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment really helped me think of the problem in a different way and I was able to find a solution.